# How to prevent NullPointerException in the finally clause in a Java Class in Domino agent

Tags: java, lotus-domino

Java debugging information only returns null without stating the actual cause of the error in the finally clause of the try/catch and not sure on how to get rid of this error message or the cause of it which is related to the recycle method called.

**Below is the error log:**

```
Agent Manager: Agent printing: Create Report final insert error:  null
Agent Manager: Agent  error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at JavaAgent.createReport(Unknown Source)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Below are the functions being called**

```
        private void createReport() {
        Integer qCount = 0;
        Document qDoc = null;
        ViewNavigator vNav = null;

        try {
            qView = currentDatabase.getView("RecsByRNo");
            qDoc = qView.getFirstDocument();
            vNav = qView.createViewNav();

            while (qDoc != null) {

                String qNo = qDoc.getItemValueString("RNo");
                String qType = qDoc.getItemValueString("EType");
                String qStatus = qDoc.getItemValueString("Status");
                String qBy = qDoc.getItemValueString("RBy");

                Document tmpReqDoc = qView.getNextDocument(qDoc);
                qDoc.recycle();
                qDoc = tmpReqDoc;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logErrors("Create Report error: ", e);

        } finally {
            try {
                qView.recycle();
                qDoc.recycle();
                vNav.recycle();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               logErrors("Create Report final insert error: ", e);
            }
        }

        agentLogger.LogAction("<<< Count: " + qCount + " >>>");
    }

    private void logErrors(String t, Exception e) {
        agentLogger.LogError(t + " " + e.getMessage());
        agentLogger.LogError(t + " " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
        System.out.println(t + " " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: replace `qView.recycle()` with `if (qView != null) qView.recycle();`, same for the other 2?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of `recycle()` should be updated in the reverse order of creation. The `qDoc` and `vNav` objects has been created from `qView` object. If recycle on `qView` is called first then other objects become null as well. And it's always good practice to check for `null` before closing object in the `finally` block.

```
finally {
            try {
                if(vNav != null) vNav.recycle();
                if(qDoc != null) qDoc.recycle();
                if(qView != null) qView.recycle();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               logErrors("Create Report final insert error: ", e);
            }
        }
```